# Will whole Haskell be a part of Curry?

Tags: haskell, logic-programming, curry

I found [Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_%28programming_language%29) on Wikipedia. It says Curry is nearly a superset but not because of lacking of something.

I'd like to see it support whole Haskell. Did they plan to implement Haskell as a part of Curry?

Comment: When it comes to PLs, it is not a matter of implementing one on top of the other I think. DSLs, Polymorphism and Libraries are a science on their own. There should be always a benefit like higher level of abstraction, saving lines of code & development time etc.. What would be the benefit here I wonder?